# FilterDefinition serialization does not work as expected in new MongoDb driver

Tags: mongodb

With mongodb .net driver versions earlier than 2 we built `Query<Person>` object (part of its api) and were able to serialize it into a mongodb query with `ToJson(`) method. With mongodb driver v.2.5 now we have new `FilterDefinition<Person>` to build similar queries, but serialization does not work properly anymore:

```
FilterDefinition<Person> filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(t => t.Name, "Alex");
filter.ToBsonDocument() // returns {{ "_t" : "SimpleFilterDefinition`2" }}
filter.ToJson() // returns same {{ "_t" : "SimpleFilterDefinition`2" }}
filter.ToString() // returns MongoDB.Driver.SimpleFilterDefinition`2[TestApp.Person,System.String]
```

Same happens to other type of filtering operations and other entities.
Any suggestions on how to make serialization work right?

Comment: Can you show the before and after serialization comparison ?

Comment: Before: `Query<Person>.EQ(t => t.Name, "Alex").ToJson()`;

After: `Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(t => t.Name, "Alex").ToJson()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
        var personSerializer = new MongoClient()
            .GetDatabase("test")
            .Settings
            .SerializerRegistry
            .GetSerializer<Person>();

        var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(x => x.FirstName, "Bob");

        var doc = filter.Render(personSerializer, BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry);

        Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

Comment: BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance is of type BsonDocumentSerializer, while compiler expects it to be of IBsonSerializer<Person>, which I'm not sure how to instantiate. Please advise

Comment: @YMC I've updated the answer, sorry about that - The Typed Serializer will be on the Settings object within the Database you're using.

Comment: now it seems to work fine and serialization works properly. Thanks! Still do not understand why former approach does not work, though ToJson() method looks like supposed to service exactly this goal of serializing mongo query, I think it could be an mongodb driver bug

Comment: ToJson looks like an extension method on just object?